# Garbage collection issue on apache kafka

Tags: python, node.js, apache-kafka

```
2017-06-21T18:54:05.285-0700: 282.369: [GC pause (young), 0.0396040 secs]
   [Parallel Time: 37.6 ms, GC Workers: 2]
      [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 282369.3, Avg: 282369.3, Max: 282369.3, Diff: 0.0]
      [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 6.4, Avg: 6.4, Max: 6.4, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 12.9]
      [Update RS (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.0]
         [Processed Buffers: Min: 0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0, Diff: 0, Sum: 0]
      [Scan RS (ms): Min: 0.2, Avg: 0.2, Max: 0.2, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.3]
      [Code Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.1, Avg: 0.4, Max: 0.7, Diff: 0.6, Sum: 0.8]
      [Object Copy (ms): Min: 30.1, Avg: 30.5, Max: 30.8, Diff: 0.7, Sum: 60.9]
      [Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.0]
      [GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.1]
      [GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 37.5, Avg: 37.5, Max: 37.5, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 75.0]
      [GC Worker End (ms): Min: 282406.8, Avg: 282406.8, Max: 282406.8, Diff: 0.0]
   [Code Root Fixup: 0.7 ms]
   [Code Root Migration: 0.7 ms]
   [Clear CT: 0.1 ms]
   [Other: 0.6 ms]
      [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
      [Ref Proc: 0.2 ms]
      [Ref Enq: 0.0 ms]
      [Free CSet: 0.2 ms]
   [Eden: 190.0M(190.0M)->0.0B(190.0M) Survivors: 14.0M->14.0M Heap: 581.0M(4096.0M)->392.0M(4096.0M)]
 [Times: user=0.08 sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs]
```

I am running kafka server and working with node and python. As soon as I start my node server, kafka runs garbage collector runs and prints above in the logs:

Due to this python is not able to publish to queue and node is not able to consume.

Answer (score 0):

The garbage collection logged shouldn't be an issue - it doesn't appear unhealthy. Most likely it's not related to your publication and consumption problems. But you haven't described in detail what your issues with producing/consuming actually is, so it's not easy to advise.